# C - printf and scanf buffer

Tags: c, buffer, printf, stdout, scanf

I'm sorry about the generic title, but i didn't find anything better.
And I'm sorry if the question is stupid but I'm a novice and I could not find anything of use to me.

I have written this code to solve a simple problem: you have a sequence of positive integers terminated by a negative: for every integer you have to print a corresponding amount of `*` characters and go to a new line.

The code DOES WORK but I can't really understand WHY.

```
int main()
{
    int d=0,i;
    while (d>=0){
        scanf("%d",&d);
        for (i=0;i<d;i++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I did a bit of research and I understand that terminal gives the integer sequence to `scanf` only when I press return.
I thought it would work this way:

- `scanf` gets the integer sequence it registers the first one while the others are discarded
- prints the amount of `*`s corresponding to the  first integer

Instead it seems that `scanf` reads the first integer, then printf sends it to a buffer then the cycle restarts and `scanf` gets the second integer and so on.
When the last positive integer is reached `printf` flushes the buffer.

Am I wrong? And if not, why does it work this way?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. I know im registering the value into d, but shouldn't I be able to register only one value at a time? And shouldn't the printf function immediately print everything as soon as the first integer is read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf()` does reads the first integer, then printf sends it to a buffer then the cycle *continues* and scanf gets the second integer and so on. *After*  a negative integer is reached *the rest of stdin is ignored*.  `stdout` is flushed with each `\n` and program ending.

Comment: How does it decide when is the right moment to start ? I mean how does it know that the scanf are going to end? I'm a bit confused...

Comment: When the function `scanf()` is executed, it looks to its format `"%d"` in this case.  The format is parsed.  The format's first directive is `"%d"` which says to look to `stdin` for an `int`.  `stdin` is usually line buffered, meaning anything typed is not available to routines like `scanf()` until `\n` occurs.  After various text is typed and a `\n` occurs, the text is read one `char` at a time by `scanf()`.  `scanf()`, looking for an `int` first consumes optional leading white-space.  Then looks for a legal sequence of `int` characters and continues until a illegitimate `char is found.

Comment: More - `scanf()` then puts _back_ the illegitimate `char` for subsequent calls reading `stdin`.  If more than 1 number was entered on `stdin` like `"  123  456 -1 789\n"`, scanning stops with the  illegitimate `char` of space at the end of  `"  123 "`.  The next call to `scanf()` reads in `"  456 "` and puts back the final space.  A third call read `" -1 "`, puts back the final space.  Since the program ends, the final `" 789\n"` is never read.

Answer (score 0):

This should clear your ideas about `scanf`

http://home.datacomm.ch/t_wolf/tw/c/getting_input.html